# List implementation with no type

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

and

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

They both compile.

Comment: It's too bad there isn't any [documentation for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9) or you could just look it up.

Comment: @DavidConrad One could argue every syntax question could be solved by looking at documentation, yet there are countless on StackOverflow.  Many of the top answers to these types of questions are a direct answer followed by referenced documentation, which is helpful when people don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference. The latter is a shortcut introduced in [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html).